Static readonly field value gets replaced
.NET 8 Blazor
Static class, static fields
I am not sure what to call this issue, but I have a static read-only field where its value gets reflected as another value within the containing static class. I am not sure what would cause this or where to start looking. Any help would be appreciated.
The only forms in which this is used is =, ==, !=.
For example:
if (SOM == SystemOfMeasure.Imperial)
{
    UOM = UnitOfMeasure.IN;
}
else
{
    UOM = UnitOfMeasure.MM;
}

See screenshot of IntelliSense:

public static class UnitOfMeasure
{
    public static float MMToIn = (1 / 25.4F);
    public static float inToMM = 25.4F;

    public class Unit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public float DefaultStep { get; set; }
        public int DefaultDecimalPlaces { get; set; }

        public string DrawingPostFix { get; set; }

        public float ConversionFactor { get; set; }

        public bool ShowUOM { get; set; } = true;

        public float Convert(Unit unitFrom, float value)
        {
            return (unitFrom.ConversionFactor / ConversionFactor) * value;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Unit c1, Unit c2)
        {
            return c1?.Equals(c2) ?? false;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Unit c1, Unit c2)
        {
            return !c1?.Equals(c2) ?? true;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }

            var objectToCompareWith = (Unit)obj;

            return objectToCompareWith.Name == Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Name);
        }
    }
    
    public static readonly Unit Currency = new()
    {
        Name = "Currency",
        DisplayName = "Currency",
        Description = "Currency",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit IN = new()
    {
        Name = "in",
        DisplayName = "in",
        Description = "inches",
        DefaultStep = .001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 4,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit MM = new()
    {
        Name = "mm",
        DisplayName = "mm",
        Description = "millimeter",
        DefaultStep = .1F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = MMToIn
    };

    public static readonly Unit SquareIN = new()
    {
        Name = "in²",
        DisplayName = "in²",
        Description = "inches squared",
        DefaultStep = .001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 5,
        DrawingPostFix = "in²",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit SquareMM = new()
    {
        Name = "mm²",
        DisplayName = "mm²",
        Description = "inches squared",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "mm²",
        ConversionFactor = Pow(MMToIn, 2)
    };

    public static readonly Unit CubicIN = new()
    {
        Name = "in³",
        DisplayName = "in³",
        Description = "inches cubed",
        DefaultStep = .001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 5,
        DrawingPostFix = "in³",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit CubicMM = new()
    {
        Name = "mm³",
        DisplayName = "mm³",
        Description = "inches cubed",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "mm³",
        ConversionFactor = Pow(MMToIn, 3)
    };

    public static readonly Unit L = new()
    {
        Name = "L",
        DisplayName = "L",
        Description = "Liters",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 4,
        DrawingPostFix = "L",
        ConversionFactor = 1 / 0.01638706F
    };

    public static readonly Unit Gallon = new()
    {
        Name = "gal",
        DisplayName = "gal",
        Description = "Gallons",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 4,
        DrawingPostFix = "gal",
        ConversionFactor = 1 / 0.004329F
    };

    public static readonly Unit ML = new()
    {
        Name = "ml",
        DisplayName = "ml",
        Description = "milliliters",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 4,
        DrawingPostFix = "ml",
        ConversionFactor = 1 / 16.3871F
    };

    public static readonly Unit MG = new()
    {
        Name = "mg",
        DisplayName = "mg",
        Description = "milligrames",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 0,
        DrawingPostFix = "mg",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit G = new()
    {
        Name = "g",
        DisplayName = "g",
        Description = "grames",
        DefaultStep = .001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 4,
        DrawingPostFix = "g",
        ConversionFactor = 1000
    };

    public static readonly Unit KG = new()
    {
        Name = "kg",
        DisplayName = "kg",
        Description = "kilogrames",
        DefaultStep = .001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 4,
        DrawingPostFix = "kg",
        ConversionFactor = 1000000
    };

    public static readonly Unit DEG = new()
    {
        Name = "deg",
        DisplayName = "deg",
        Description = "degrees",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 1,
        DrawingPostFix = "˚",
        ConversionFactor = PI / 180
    };

    public static readonly Unit Percent = new()
    {
        Name = "%",
        DisplayName = "%",
        Description = "percent",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 0,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit MGPerCubicIN = new()
    {
        Name = "mg/in³",
        DisplayName = "mg/in³",
        Description = "mg per inches cubed",
        DefaultStep = .00001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 0,
        DrawingPostFix = "mg/in³",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit MGPerCubicMM = new()
    {
        Name = "mg/mm³",
        DisplayName = "mg/mm³",
        Description = "mg per inches cubed",
        DefaultStep = .00001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "mg/mm³",
        ConversionFactor = 1 / Pow(MMToIn, 3)
    };

    public static readonly Unit MGPerML = new()
    {
        Name = "mg/ml",
        DisplayName = "mg/ml",
        Description = "mg per milligrames",
        DefaultStep = .00001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "mg/ml",
        ConversionFactor = 1 * 16.3871F
    };

    public static readonly Unit GPerCubicIN = new()
    {
        Name = "g/in³",
        DisplayName = "g/in³",
        Description = "g per inches cubed",
        DefaultStep = .00001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "g/in³",
        ConversionFactor = 1000
    };

    public static readonly Unit GPerCubicMM = new()
    {
        Name = "g/mm³",
        DisplayName = "g/mm³",
        Description = "g per inches cubed",
        DefaultStep = .00001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 5,
        DrawingPostFix = "g/mm³",
        ConversionFactor = 1000 / Pow(MMToIn, 3)
    };

    public static readonly Unit GPerML = new()
    {
        Name = "g/ml",
        DisplayName = "g/ml",
        Description = "g per milligrames",
        DefaultStep = .00001F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 4,
        DrawingPostFix = "g/ml",
        ConversionFactor = 1000 * 16.3871F
    };

    public static readonly Unit LBS = new()
    {
        Name = "LBS",
        DisplayName = "LBS",
        Description = "Pounds",
        DefaultStep = 5,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit Tons = new()
    {
        Name = "tons",
        DisplayName = "tons",
        Description = "Tons",
        DefaultStep = .1F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 2000
    };

    public static readonly Unit kN = new()
    {
        Name = "kN",
        DisplayName = "kN",
        Description = "kilonewton",
        DefaultStep = .1F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1 / 0.00444822F
    };

    public static readonly Unit kP = new()
    {
        Name = "kP",
        DisplayName = "kP",
        Description = "kilopond",
        DefaultStep = 10,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 1,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 2.2046226219F
    };

    public static readonly Unit MPA = new()
    {
        Name = "MPa",
        DisplayName = "MPa",
        Description = "Megapascal",
        DefaultStep = 10,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 145
    };

    public static readonly Unit RPM = new()
    {
        Name = "RPM",
        DisplayName = "RPM",
        Description = "RPM",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit Hertz = new()
    {
        Name = "Hz",
        DisplayName = "Hz",
        Description = "Hz",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 3,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 60.0F
    };

    public static readonly Unit TPM = new()
    {
        Name = "TPM",
        DisplayName = "Tablets Per Minute",
        Description = "Tablets Per Minute",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit TPH = new()
    {
        Name = "TPH",
        DisplayName = "Tablets Per Hour",
        Description = "Tablets Per Hour",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit HR = new()
    {
        Name = "hr",
        DisplayName = "hr",
        Description = "hours",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit Tablets = new()
    {
        Name = "Tablets",
        DisplayName = "Tablets",
        Description = "Tablets",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1,
        ShowUOM = false
    };

    public static readonly Unit ToolStationQty = new()
    {
        Name = "ToolStationQty",
        DisplayName = "Tool Station Qty",
        Description = "Tool Station Qty",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 0,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit MainCompressionRollerQty = new()
    {
        Name = "MainCompressionRollerQty",
        DisplayName = "Main Compression Rollers",
        Description = "Main Compression Rollers",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 0,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit TipQty = new()
    {
        Name = "TipQty",
        DisplayName = "Tip Qty",
        Description = "Tip Qty",
        DefaultStep = 1,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 0,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1
    };

    public static readonly Unit ThickToWidthRatio = new()
    {
        Name = "ThickToWidthRatio",
        DisplayName = "Thickness To Width",
        Description = "Thickness To Width",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1,
        ShowUOM = false
    };

    public static readonly Unit CornerRadiusToWidth = new()
    {
        Name = "CornerRadiusToWidth",
        DisplayName = "Corner Radius To Width",
        Description = "Corner Radius To Width",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1,
        ShowUOM = false
    };

    public static readonly Unit CupToThickRatio = new()
    {
        Name = "CupToThickRatio",
        DisplayName = "Cup To Thickness",
        Description = "Cup To Thickness",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1,
        ShowUOM = false
    };

    public static readonly Unit LengthToWidthRatio = new()
    {
        Name = "LengthToWidthRatio",
        DisplayName = "Length To Width",
        Description = "Length To Width",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1,
        ShowUOM = false
    };

    public static readonly Unit EndRadiusToWidthRatio = new()
    {
        Name = "EndRadiusToWidthRatio",
        DisplayName = "End Radius To Width",
        Description = "End Radius To Width",
        DefaultStep = .01F,
        DefaultDecimalPlaces = 2,
        DrawingPostFix = "",
        ConversionFactor = 1,
        ShowUOM = false
    };    
}

Static read-only fields never change values

Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  One thing to note: while your static fields are readonly, your Unit type is mutable, so even if the value of MM is unchanged the contents of the Unit to which it refers could be overwritten.

Using Blazor Webassembly could this happen due to the internal serialization of the class? I do not replace the underlying value anywhere. What would you suggest?

readonly doesn't mean that the Unit object can't be changed, it just prevents that another value gets assigned to the field. Put a breakpoint in one of Units properties and check if and where the setter gets called after the initial initialization.

Found this https://devcodef1.com/news/1329597/static-field-value-mismatch-in-net-8-blazor#:~:text=One%20way%20to%20work%20around%20this%20issue%20is,be%20initialized%20during%20initialization%20or%20within%20a%20constructor.
I have adjusted to follow this method and within the child class I check to see if the value has already been set.

What would you suggest? I would suggest making your Unit type be immutable.  At the minimum change your set properties to init, e.g. public string Name { get; init; }

@dbc that did not work. This is what I have going:
    public class SetOnce<T>
    {
        private bool set;
        private T value;

        public T Value
        {
            get { return value; }
            set
            {
                if (set) return;
                set = true;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator T(SetOnce<T> toConvert)
        {
            return toConvert.value;
        }
    }


This needs a [MRE].  The question states that "Static readonly field value gets replaced" but [unless I'm blind] I see no code to demonstrate the problem.

You do this:
public static readonly Unit Currency = new() {...}

Which creates a field with a reference to an instance of Unit.  Once created you can't change the reference.  It always points to the same instance.
However, Unit is a class with open access (public getters and setters), so you can mutate the contents of the object to your heart's content [which is probably what you're doing].
If you want to make the Unit content immutable, you should define Unit as a record with all the properties as {get; init;}.  See the MS documentation on records for more detail - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record.
